# nativescript push notifications with aws sns

Tags: nativescript, amazon-sns

I'm using nativescript-vue for client application, and AWS for server.
I'm looking for a way to send push notifications with SNS, and currently It looks like (NS) supports firebase only as push notification provider.

Does anybody have experience with such a case?

thanks

Comment: {N} doesn't limit you form accessing any device / third party APIs. There is no readymade plugin available today for SNS, but you may still write one Or just include the native library and access the same within your project.

Comment: just include the native library and access the same within your project- can you add a sample or link?

Comment: Refer [Building Plugins](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/building-plugins). Before you must get familiar with Marshalling native code to JS ([iOS](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview) / [Android](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/marshalling/overview)).

Comment: @LiorGoldemberg Did you ever find a solution for using SNS in NS?